# Pasar mediante AJAX distintos inputs

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Buenas estoy haciendo un módulo que se me esta complicando un poquito.

Por un lado tengo unas opciones que pueden ser seleccionadas y eso tiene que arrojar unos resultados a través de AJAX.

**Pongo una parte de las zonas que se seleccionan:**

```
<div class="collap funciona" id="zonasl">
  <h4>ZONAS L <span class="pull-right"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></span></h4>
</div>
<span id="listaZonasL" class=zonasl style="">
  <span class="inputGroup" style="margin:0px;">
  <input id="BrazosE" name="BrazosE" type="checkbox"/>
  <label for="BrazosE">Brazos Enteros</label>
</span>
<span class="inputGroup" style="margin:0px;">
  <input id="PiernasE" name="PiernasE" type="checkbox"/>
  <label for="PiernasE">Piernas Enteras</label>
</span>
<span class="inputGroup" style="margin:0px;">
  <input id="ZonaI" name="Intima" type="checkbox"/>
  <label for="ZonaI">Zona Íntima</label>
</span>
```

Luego en otra columna, hay una figura humana, que cuando haces check en una opción de las de antes, se carga una zona en el cuerpo.

```
$('#BrazosE').change(function() { $('#imgBrazosEnteros').toggle() });
$('#PiernasE').change(function() { $('#imgPiernasEnteras').toggle() });
$('#ZonaI').change(function() { $('#imgZonaIntima').toggle() });
```

Y por ultimo en otra columna, mostrare todas las zonas seleccionadas con su precio, que el resultado saldrá con AJAX a través de las zonas que seleccionemos.

**AJAX**

```
$(function(){
  $("#BrazosE").change(function(e){
    var id ="";
      if ($("#BrazosE").val() !=null){
        id = $("#BrazosE").val();
      }
      $.ajax({
          url: "getZonas.php",
          type: "post",
          dataType: "html",
          data: {
          'id': id,
          },
          success: function (resultado){
            $("#resva").html(resultado);
          }
        });
  });
  });
```

**DIV DONDE MUESTRO EL RESULTADO AJAX**

```
<div class=""id="resva">
```

El problema de esto, es que solo se como pasar un campo seleccionado, y claro todo se me complica más, porque el AJAX quiero que actue cuando el checkbox de las opciones cambia, no con un botón y formulario. Alguna sugerencia por favor?

Comment: Pues en vez de mandar un `id` unico, manda un array de id's en un string. luego cuando vayas a hacer algo, pasas el string a array de nuevo e iteras..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estoy viendo que tienes varios problemillas en tu código.

Tienes dos funciones `change()` asociadas al mismo elemento **HTML**, esto te va ocasionar problemas. Lo mejor sería unificar ambas funciones en una, de tal manera que hicieras el `toogle()` y el `ajax()` en una misma.

Ahora, entrando en el tema del `ajax()`, lo que yo haría sería tener una misma función para todos los **checkbox** y que detectase el que se ha cambiado para enviar el **ID** del mismo.

**JQUERY**

```
$(function(){
  $(":checkbox").change(function(e){
    var brazos = '';
    var piernas = '';
    var zona = '';

    if ($('#BrazosE').is(':checked')) {
        brazos = $('#BrazosE').attr('id');
    }
    else {
        brazos = '';
    }

    if ($('#PiernasE').is(':checked')) {
        piernas = $('#BrazosE').attr('id');
    }
    else {
        piernas = '';
    }

    if ($('#ZonaI').is(':checked')) {
        zona = $('#BrazosE').attr('id');
    }
    else {
        zona = '';
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: "getZonas.php",
      type: "post",
      dataType: "html",
      data: {
        'brazos':brazos,
        'piernas':piernas,
        'zona':zona
      },
      success: function (resultado){
        $("#resva").html(resultado);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Esto lo que haría sería hacer la llamada AJAX solamente de un **checkbox** que al cambiar de estado haya quedado seleccionado y enviaría por **POST** la **ID** de dicho elemento.

Me parece que esto es lo que tratabas de hacer.

Comment: Hola @PHPMyguel estoy intentando probarlo, pero falta algún carácter, estoy buscandolo...

Comment: Ya está, se me había quedado sin cerrar un paréntesis.

Comment: Si que funciona, me va pasando según voy pulsando, hay forma que al deseleccionar también se quite? @PHPMyguel

Comment: Le he añadido un **else** a la condición **if ($(this).val() !=null && $(this).is(':checked'))**, para que cuando se deseleccione vacíe el **div** en el que pintas el resultado del **AJAX**

Comment: Vale si lo hace, pero no respeta si pulso uno y luego desactivo otro... luego intento traérmelo así a getZonas  `$BrazosE =$_POST['BrazosE'];`

Comment: Si explicas el comportamiento que esperas que realice cuando seleccionas uno y seleccionas otro quizás se te podrá ayudar. Deberías responderte preguntas como "¿Deseo que en el div **resva** se muestren varias resultados a la vez?", en caso afirmativo "¿Quiero que al deseleccionar uno desaparezca la respuesta asociada a ese checkbox? En cuanto al tema de recuperar la variable enviada por POST, estás haciéndolo mal. En la llamada ajax el parámetro que envías es **ID**, para recuperarlo en tu PHP deberías hacerlo de esta manera: **$_POST['id']**

Comment: Además, sabes de algún tutoria para formar un arreglo en getZonas.php ?? y al mandar todo como `id` como diferencio los datos cuando llegan por AJAX? @PHPMyguel

Comment: De todas formas esto ya se aleja de la pregunta que se trata aquí. Lo apropiado sería que formularas una nueva pregunta con las dudas que te surjan a partir de esto.

Comment: Justo es lo que comentas, piensa que todo lo que marque el los seleccionables tiene que aparecer en el resultado, y según deseleccione se quite tal cual deseleccione.... y no puedo recibirlos todos asi no?  $_POST['id']

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88244/discussion-between-phpmyguel-and-miguel).

Comment: Perdona @PHPMyguel, hay alguna forma de que solo muestre el que esta marcado o enviado, esque como siempre manda todos aun que esten vacios no hay forma de mostrar una lista solo con lo elegidos